# Linking error with CMake's `ExternalProject`

Tags: c++, cmake

I am starting a project with [GNU MP](https://gmplib.org/), and thought it might be useful for CMake to take care of the library. So I am trying to use `ExternalProject` of CMake (never used `ExternalProject` before). Also I fortunately found a nice code which satisfies my needs. Below is a code I have written.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)

include(ExternalProject)
include(ProcessorCount)

project(proj)

# BELOW SOURCE IS MOSTLY FROM
# https://go.googlesource.com/gollvm/+/96cc8367c6d13a58fccf1f0c5e262d03df742451/CMakeLists.txt

processorcount(PROCESSOR_COUNT)

set(EXTINSTALLDIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/external/install")
set(EXTLIBDIR "${EXTINSTALLDIR}/lib")
set(EXTINCLUDEDIR "${EXTINSTALLDIR}/include")
set(EXTCPPFLAGS "CFLAGS=-I${EXTINCLUDEDIR}")
if(NOT "${CMAKE_SYSROOT}" STREQUAL "")
    string(APPEND EXTCPPFLAGS " -fPIC -DPIC")
endif()
set(EXTLDFLAGS "LDFLAGS=-L${EXTLIBDIR}")
set(EXTCC "CC=${CMAKE_C_COMPILER}" "CXX=${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}")

find_package(Threads REQUIRED)

ExternalProject_Add(local_libgmp
    URL https://gmplib.org/download/gmp/gmp-6.3.0.tar.xz
    DOWNLOAD_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/external-downloads
    BINARY_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/external/gmp-build
    SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/external/gmp
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND <SOURCE_DIR>/configure --enable-cxx --prefix=${EXTINSTALLDIR} ${EXTCPPFLAGS} ${EXTLDFLAGS} ${EXTCC}
    BUILD_COMMAND make install -j${PROCESSOR_COUNT}
    LOG_CONFIGURE 1
    LOG_BUILD 1
    LOG_INSTALL 1
    TEST_COMMAND make check -j${PROCESSOR_COUNT}
)
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}::libgmp STATIC IMPORTED)
#ExternalProject_Get_Property(local_libgmp BINARY_DIR)
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME}::libgmp PROPERTIES
    IMPORTED_LOCATION ${EXTLIBDIR}/libgmp.a
)
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}::libgmpxx STATIC IMPORTED)
#ExternalProject_Get_Property(local_libgmp BINARY_DIR)
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME}::libgmpxx PROPERTIES
    IMPORTED_LOCATION ${EXTLIBDIR}/libgmpxx.a
)
add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME}::libgmp local_libgmp)
add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME}::libgmpxx local_libgmp)

# END

add_executable(Test test.cpp)
target_include_directories(Test PRIVATE ${EXTINCLUDEDIR})
target_link_directories(Test PRIVATE ${EXTLIBDIR})
target_link_libraries(Test PRIVATE pthread ${PROJECT_NAME}::libgmp ${PROJECT_NAME}::libgmpxx)
```

The directory is as follows:

```
proj
|  build
|- CMakeLists.txt
|- test.cpp
```

And `test.cpp` contains the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <gmpxx.h>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;
    std::cout << 11_mpz + 12_mpz << std::endl;
}
```

`cmake --fresh ..` works fine in any case, but it fails to link while `make`. For those who are interested, below is a log after running `make`:

```
[  9%] Completed 'local_libgmp'
[ 81%] Built target local_libgmp
[ 90%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Test.dir/test.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable Test
/usr/bin/ld: external/install/lib/libgmpxx.a(osmpz.o): in function `operator<<(std::ostream&, __mpz_struct const*)':
osmpz.cc:(.text+0x58): undefined reference to `__gmpz_get_str'
/usr/bin/ld: external/install/lib/libgmpxx.a(osdoprnti.o): in function `__gmp_doprnt_integer_ostream(std::ostream&, doprnt_params_t*, char*)':
osdoprnti.cc:(.text+0x7c): undefined reference to `__gmp_doprnt_integer'
/usr/bin/ld: osdoprnti.cc:(.text+0x88): undefined reference to `__gmp_asprintf_final'
/usr/bin/ld: external/install/lib/libgmpxx.a(osfuns.o):(.data.rel.ro+0x8): undefined reference to `__gmp_asprintf_memory'
/usr/bin/ld: external/install/lib/libgmpxx.a(osfuns.o):(.data.rel.ro+0x10): undefined reference to `__gmp_asprintf_reps'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Test.dir/build.make:99: Test] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:111: CMakeFiles/Test.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

I couldn't figure out what's causing the linking error. What causes the problem, and how can I fix it?

gcc version is 12.3.0, although this should not be the main cause.

Edit: I don't think the linked question answers this problem. The linked question doesn't explain the order of linking in `target_link_libraries`, which is the main and the only cause of the problem here.

Comment: `${PROJECT_NAME}::libgmp ${PROJECT_NAME}::libgmpxx` - Since C++ gmp library depends on C one, the **order** of linking should be **inversed**. See [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix/24675715#24675715).

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks for the answer. Still I couldn't understand the problem. There is no place in my code which writes gmpxx before gmp. Could you please explain what's happening behind the scenes?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I just figured it out, thanks a lot!